# How to filter JSON Data Array based on picker selection?

Tags: swiftui

I want to filter my data array based on the picker selection. My question is how to populate/filter cities array based on any selected country.  The sample code is as follows:

```
static var countries: [String: [WorldData]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: worldData,
            by: { $0.country }
        )
    }



 static var city: [String: [WorldData]] {
        Dictionary(
            grouping: worldData,
            by: { $0.city }
        )

    }

Picker(selection: $Country,
                   label: Text("Country")) {

                    ForEach(self.countries.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                        Text(key).tag(key)


                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good sleep, I solved my own problem. If anyone needs it, here is the solution:

```
    static func filteredCities(key:String) -> [String: [WorldData]] {
            var cities: [String: [WorldData]] {
                Dictionary(
                    grouping: worldData.filter{$0.species == key},
                    by: { $0.city }
                )
            }
            return cities
   }
```